# Get rows filtered by month from a date column

Tags: c#, linq, date

I have a datatable where the records have  date field column with values like

```
11/1/2012
12/21/2012
12/22/2012
1/3/2013
1/5/2013
1/6/2013
1/7/2013
etc.
```

I want to filter the records and get only current month records i.e get only those rows where date is equal to current month (which will be find by DateTime.now). How can we do this with Linq and c#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the type of the column is already `DateTime`:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var thisMonthRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r =>  r.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName").Year  == now.Year
              && r.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName").Month == now.Month);
```

If you want a new DataTable from the filtered rows use `CopyToDataTable`:

```
DataTable table = thisMonthRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: How to put thisMonthRows in datatable?

Answer (score 1):

Get first day of month and filter by that date:

```
 DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
 DateTime firstDayOfMonth = today.AddDays(1 - today.Day);
 // or new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);

 var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             where row.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= firstDayOfMonth
             select row;
```

Of course, this is working if you don't have records with dates in future (e.g. for next month). If you do, then better introduce new range variable to avoid parsing date twice:

```
 var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             let date = row.Field<DateTime>("Date")
             where date.Year == today.Year && 
                   date.Month == today.Month
             select row;
```

Comment: You've got an off-by-one error in your `firstDayOfMonth`, and I'm not sure this is what OP is after anyway.

Comment: And the reason of downvote is? Because there is only one date parsing and clear intent of filtering?

Comment: @Rawling what is off-by-one in English?

Comment: I mean `firstDayOfMonth` will be the last day of the previous month (e.g. on the first, `today.Day` will be `1` so you'll add `-1` days)